# Body of outlook email does not copy to excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The following code works It will open up designated file from designated email. However it will not Seperate the body message into different line in excel, any suggestions?

```
For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
    '~~> This will give you the contents of your email
    '~~> on separate lines
    Debug.Print MyAr(i)
Next i
    End With
```

---

```
Const xlUp As Long = -4162

Sub ExportToExcel(MyMail As MailItem)
    Dim strID As String, olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strFileName As String

'~~> Excel Variables
Dim oXLApp As Object, oXLwb As Object, oXLws As Object
Dim lRow As Long

strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)

'~~> Establish an EXCEL application object
On Error Resume Next
Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

'~~> If not found then create new instance
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

'~~> Show Excel
oXLApp.Visible = True

'~~> Open the relevant file
Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ltorres\Documents\multiplier.xlsx")

'~~> Set the relevant output sheet. Change as applicable
Set oXLws = oXLwb.Sheets("Sheet1")

lRow = oXLws.Range("A" & oXLws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'~~> Write to outlook
With oXLws
Dim MyAr() As String

MyAr = Split(olMail.Body, vbCrLf)

For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
    '~~> This will give you the contents of your email
    '~~> on separate lines
    Debug.Print MyAr(i)
Next i
    End With

'~~> Close and Clean up Excel
oXLwb.Close (True)
oXLApp.Quit
Set oXLws = Nothing
Set oXLwb = Nothing
Set oXLApp = Nothing

Set olMail = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Should `lRow = oXLws.Range("A" & oXLApp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1` be referring to the rows in `oXLws` not `oXLApp`? Also, is anything appearing in the immediate window from `Debug.Print MyAr(i)`?

Comment: @jordan Correct I have fixed it and what is appearing in excel is the subject and the sender column A and B , but not the body however in the debug.print it's showing the body of the email. ***Please note I would like to separate the body of the email into different lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `lRow` in the `With` statement, but you also need to add 1 row each time there is a line break as defined by your `MyAr`, try:

```
With oXLws
lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Dim MyAr() As String
MyAr = Split(olMail.Body, vbCrLf)
For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
    .Range("A" & lRow).Value = MyAr(i)
    lRow = lRow + 1
Next i
End With
```

Comment: thanks this should get me to the direction I want to go with